# Rails: Cucumber forgetting CanCan Authorisations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, devise, cancan

I'm trying to write up some cucumber tests to ensure cancan permissions are set correctly, and I'm having an odd problem:

When I log in through the following code, capybara says I've logged in as expected. However, when I then go to a resource which requires the given login, I get CanCan's "not authorized" message. Capybara prints out "logged in as testsuperadmin with role superadmin" (the desired role) on the very same "denied access" page.

Accessing the same page manually, not through cucumber/capybara, authorization is granted & everything works fine. Authentication is handled by devise.

I've tried adding @allow-rescue above the scenario and ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = true to features/support/env.rb - neither had any effect.

Any suggestions? This one really has me stumped.

Cheers...

```
 #app/models/ability.rb
 class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.role? :superadmin
        can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role? :admin
        can :manage, [Broker, User]
    elsif user.role? :staff
        can :manage, Broker
    elsif user.role? :broker
        can :manage, Broker, :user_id => user.id
        can :read, Broker
    elsif user.role? :customer
        can :manage, User, :id => user.id
    else can :read, [Broker]
    end
  end
end



# features/brokers.feature
@allow-rescue
Scenario: Successfully create Broker
    Given I am logged in as "testsuperadmin" with password "testpassword"
    When I go to the create broker page
    Then show me the page # Authorization denied here, but signed in successfully if this line moved between "Given I am logged in" ... and "When I go to to create broker page"
    ......



# features/steps/devise_steps.rb
Given /^I am logged in as "([^\"]*)" with password "([^\"]*)"$/ do |username, password|
    #visit path_to(sign in page)
    visit "/users/sign_out"
    visit "/users/sign_in"
    fill_in("user[username]", :with => username)
    fill_in("user[password]", :with => password)
    click_button("Sign in")
end



  # app/controllers/brokers_controller.rb
  class BrokersController < ApplicationController
    load_and_authorize_resource

    # ...
    def new
      @broker = Broker.new

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.xml  { render :xml => @broker }
      end
    end
```

Comment: Hello. I'm having the exact same issue, and I'm wondering if you managed to find a solution in the past months. Thanks for your feedback! Regards.